# How to improve performance of UCollectionView containing lots of small images?

Tags: ios, image, performance, memory, uicollectionview

In my iOS app I have `UICollectionView` that displays around 1200 small (35x35 points) images. The images are stored in application bundle.

I am correctly reusing `UICollectionViewCell`s but still have performance problems that vary depending on how I address image loading:

- My app is application extension and those have limited memory (40 MB in this case). Putting all 1200 images to Assets catalog and loading them using `UIImage(named: "imageName")` resulted in memory crashes - system cached images which filled up the memory. At some point the app needs to allocate bigger portions of memory but these were not available because of cached images. Instead of triggering memory warning and cleaning the cache, operating system just killed the app.
- I changed the approach to avoid images caching. I put images to my project (not to asssets catalog) as png files and I am loading them using `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("imageName", ofType: "png")` now. The app no longer crashes due to memory error but loading of single image takes much longer and fast scrolling is lagging even on the newest iPhones.

I have full controll over the images and can transform them for example to .jpeg or optimize them (I already tried [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com) and some other options without success).

How can I resolve both these performance problems at once?

---

**EDIT 1:**

I also tried loading images in background thread. This is code from my subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
private func loadImageNamed(name: String) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { [weak self] () in
        let image = bundle.pathForResource(name, ofType: "png")?.CGImage
        if name == self?.displayedImageName {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if name == self?.displayedImageName {
                    self?.contentView.layer.contents = image
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

This makes scrolling smooth without consuming additional memory for caching **but** when scrolling to some location programatically (for example when `UICollectionView` scrolls to top) **it causes another problem**: During scrolling animation the images do not update (scroll is too fast for them to load) and after scrolling is finished it takes wrong images are displayed for fraction of second - and one after another replaced with correct ones. This is very disturbing visually.

---

**EDIT 2:**

I cannot group small images into bigger composed images and display those as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31869978/311865).

Reasons:

- Consider different screen sizes and orientations. There would have to be precomposed images for each of them which would make the app download huge.
- The small images can by displayed in different order, some of them might be hidden in some situation. I surrely cannot have precomposed images for each possible combinations and orders.

Comment: You need some sort of cache which can be populated from your standard images on demand but then accessed quickly once things are up and running so scrolling etc is smooth. The following link seems to provide such a mechanism. Looks like it uses memory mapped files and avoids much of the overhead. Might be worth a look? https://github.com/path/FastImageCache

Answer (score 5):

I can propose alternative way that probably can solve your problem:
Consider to render blocks of images to single composed images. Such large image should cover size of app window. For user it will be looked like collection of small images, but technically it will be table of large images.

Your's current layout:

```
 |      |      |      |
 | cell | cell | cell |  -> cells outside of screen
 |      |      |      |
************************
*|      |      |      |*
*| cell | cell | cell |* -> cells displayed on screen
*|      |      |      |*
*----------------------*
*|      |      |      |* 
*| cell | cell | cell |* -> cells displayed on screen
*|      |      |      |*
*----------------------*
*|      |      |      |*
*| cell | cell | cell |* -> cells displayed on screen
*|      |      |      |*
************************
 |      |      |      |
 | cell | cell | cell |  -> cells outside of screen
 |      |      |      |
```

Proposed layout:

```
 |                    |
 |     cell with      |
 |   composed image   |  -> cell outside of screen
 |                    |
************************
*|                    |*
*|                    |*
*|                    |* 
*|                    |* 
*|     cell with      |*
*|   composed image   |* -> cell displayed on screen
*|                    |*
*|                    |*
*|                    |* 
*|                    |* 
*|                    |*
************************
 |                    |
 |     cell with      |
 |   composed image   |  -> cell outside of screen
 |                    |
```

Ideally if you pre-render such composed images and put them to project at build time, but you can also render them in runtime. For sure first variant will work much more faster. But in any case single large image costs less memory then separate pieces of that image.

If you have possibility to pre-render them then use JPEG format. In this case probably your first solution (load images with `[UIImage imageNamed:]` on main thread) will work good because less memory used, layout is much more simpler.

If you have to render them in runtime then you will need use your current solution (do work in background), and you will still see that image misplacements when quick animation happens, but in this case it will be single misplacement (one image covers window frame), so it should look better.

If you need to know what image (original small image 35x35) user clicked, you can use `UITapGestureRecognizer`attached to cell. When gesture is recognized you can use `locationInView:` method to calculate correct index of small image.

I can't say that it 100% resolves your issue, but it makes sense to try.

Comment: This is a good idea but I unfortunatelly cannot do that - there is number of reasons why I have to display it as many small images. First, images can appear in different order each time, some may be missing etc. Second, for different screen sizes there are different images on particular screen. For example, on iPhone 6 Plus more images fits in the screen then on iPhone 5S. I would have to have separate precomposed images for each screen size and orientation and that would make app download size huge. There are more reasons why I cannot do what you suggested...

Answer (score 5):

1. There is no need to fetch image from document directory every time the cell appears.
2. Once you fetch the image you can save same in NSCache, next time you just have to get image from NSCache instead of fetching it again from document directory.
3. Create an object for NSCache objCache;
4. In your cellForItemAtIndexPath, just write down

   ```
   UIImage *cachedImage = [objCache objectForKey:arr_PathFromDocumentDirectory[indexPath.row]];

   if (cachedImage) {
       imgView_Cell.image = cachedImage;
   } else {
       dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
       dispatch_async(q, ^{
           /* Fetch the image from the Document directory... */
           [self downloadImageWithURL:arr_PathFromDocument[indexPath.row] completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, CGImageRef data, NSString* path) {
               if (succeeded) {
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       UIImage *img =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:data];
                       imgView_Cell.image = img;
                       [objCache setObject:img forKey::arr_PathFromDocument[indexPath.row]];
                   });
               }
           }];
       });
   }
   ```
5. Once you fetch the image, set it in NSCache with path. Next time it is going to check if already downloaded  then set from cache only.

If you need any assistance, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good answer and could resolve your issue. Another thing to look into would be an open source project like https://github.com/path/FastImageCache, but it uses the same principle. The issue you may still run into is the 40MB ceiling for extensions.

Comment: @mclaughlinj I don't think caching is a viable option here because of very limited available memory: 40MB for *everything*. That is for all views, animations, data structures. In addition there is very strange memory management for keyboard extension - you don't always get memory warning before the app is killed due memory limit. I have *maybe* like 10MB reserve there so I could use 5MB for caching but that is too little to be usefull.

Answer (score 3):

Change from PNG to JPEG will not help saving the memory, because when you load an image from file to memory, it's extracted from the compressed data to uncompressed bytes.

And for the performance issue, I would recommend that you load the image asynchronously and update the view by using delegate/block. And keep some images in memory(but not all of them, let's say 100)

Hope this helps!

Comment: @drasto for your "Edit 1" the problem should be that you haven't set the image of content to nil before dispatching a new task for getting the image.

Answer (score 3):

You should create an queue to load image asynchronously. The best choice is a last in first out queue. You can have look at this [LIFOOperationQueue](https://github.com/cbrauchli/LIFOOperationQueue). 
One important thing is prevent showing wrong image that need to be handle separately. To do that, when you create an operation to load the image, give it the current indexPath as identifier. And then in callback function, check if the given indexPath is visible to update the view

```
if (self.tableView.visibleIndexPath().containsObject(indexPath) {
    cell.imageView.image = img;
}
```

You should also need to custom the LIFOOperationQueue to have maximum number of task in queue so that it can remove unnecessary task. It is good to set the maximum number of task is `1.5 * numberOfVisibleCell`.

One last thing, you should create load image operation in `willDisplayCell` instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Thank you for interesting answer. However, I have some additional questions: Is there any advantage of LIFOOperationQueue over asynchronous loading by code from my EDIT 1? Will it solve the visual issue when scrolling programatically described in EDIT 1? Why should I load images in `willDisplayCell ` instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath `?

Comment: If you use the queue, you can cancel unnecessary task while your answer cant do that. It still can't resolve the visual issue so that you must do it yourself as I described in my answer. And of course, willDisplay is alway called before cellForRow, so it will be faster

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things you can do for this,

1. You should load only those images in which are reacquired and unload them when not reacquired this will make your app use less
   memory.
2. Other thing when you load image in background decode it in background thread before setting it to image view... by default
   image will decode when you set and that will happen usually on main
   thread, this will make scrolling smooth, you can decode an image by code below.

   ```
   static UIImage *decodedImageFromData:(NSData *data, BOOL isJPEG)
   {
       // Create dataProider object from provided data
       CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
       // Create CGImageRef from dataProviderObject
       CGImageRef newImage = (isJPEG) ? CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault) : CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);



   // Get width and height info from image
   const size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(newImage);
   const size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(newImage);

   // Create colorspace
   const CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   // Create context object, provide data ref if wean to store other wise NULL
   // Set width and height of image
   // Number of bits per comoponent
   // Number of bytes per row
   // set color space
   // And tell what CGBitMapInfo
   const CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate( NULL,width, height,8, width * 4, colorspace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

   //Now we can draw image
   CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), newImage);
   // Get CGImage from drwan context
   CGImageRef drawnImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
   CGContextRelease(context);
   CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

   // Create UIImage from CGImage
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:drawnImage];

   CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
   CGImageRelease(newImage);
   CGImageRelease(drawnImage);
   return image;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2):

Check this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/86365/asyncdisplaykit-tutorial-achieving-60-fps-scrolling

It uses AsyncDisplayKit to load images on a background thread.

Comment: Why not try the tutorial? It exactly solves your problem.

Comment: I am reading it right now. But it does not seems to be exactly what I need: It uses AsyncDisplayKit to load images in background and displays some placeholder while they are being loaded. But placeholders would look really bad in my case - imagine you have 1200 35x35 images in collection view, you are at the bottom of it and press a button to scroll to top. Some 1100 placeholders will be scrolled. That does not give you much feel for what you scrolled over...

Answer (score 2):

To resolve issues that are described in `EDIT 1` you should override `prepareForReuse` method in the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass and reset your layer's content to nil:

```
- (void) prepareForReuse
{
    self.contentView.layer.contents = nil;
}
```

To load your image in the background you can use the next:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* imagePath = #image_path#;
    weakself;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //load image
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

        //redraw image using device context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, 0);
        [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            strongself;
            if ([[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound) {
                cell.contentView.layer.contents = (__bridge id)(image.CGImage);
            } else {
                // cache image via NSCache with countLimit or custom approach
            }
        });
   });
}
```

How to improve:

1. Use `NSCache` or custom caching algorithm in order not to load
   images while scrolling all the time.
2. Use the proper file format. The JPEG decompression works faster for images like photographs. Use PNG for images with flat areas of
   color, sharp lines, etc.